# Excel VBA: Runtime-Error 438

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I tried to make a button and assign a macro to it.
When I hit the button to run the macro it says:

> Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

And the following code-line gets marked:

```
With Sheets("1. Stock & Demand")
    .Range("F3:F3").End(xlToRight).Offset(-2, 1).Paste
End With
```

Here is the full Code:

```
Sub NeuerTag()

'Abfrage ob der Tag eingefügt werden soll, No = QUIT'
If MsgBox("Möchtest du die Tabelle vorbereiten?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

'Copies the last three coloumns of the Worksheet 1. Stock & Demand'
With Sheets("1. Stock & Demand")
Lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
.Columns(Lastcol - 1).Resize(, 1).Copy
End With

'Selects the first empty cell in 1. Stock & Demand and pastes'
With Sheets("1. Stock & Demand")
.Range("F3:F3").End(xlToRight).Offset(-2, 1).Paste
End With

'Pastes the Today()'
With Sheets("1. Stock & Demand")
.Range("F3:ZZ3").End(xlToRight).Offset(-1, 0).Value = Date
End With

'Paste Special - Values'
With Sheets("1. Stock & Demand")
Lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
.Columns(Lastcol - 3).Resize(, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `.offset` dont have `.paste` method, so try to use `.pasteSpecial`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But now `.Columns(Lastcol - 3).Resize(, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` gives me an error. Do you know why?

Comment: i dont know which error it gives to you, but from your code probably because you dont have row parameter in `.Resize`

Comment: It says **Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error**. I added a row parameter but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: And are you sure, you have some data in cells on row 1? Because if you dont, this will throw same error for me

Comment: I want the macro to copies the last three columns of the sheet. Then find the last columns again +1 and paste the data copied before. After the macro has pasted the last three columns it should copy and paste values only (delete the formulas) of the three columns copied at first.

Comment: so your issue will be probably caused with empty column. First try to use `On Error Resume Next` if it will help you, just handle the empty columns, so script will skip them